# Generate a Recursive Tribonacci Sequence in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, recursion

I am supposed to create a function to generate a Tribonacci sequence in Python. This function must be **RECURSIVE**. Based on this, I have this code so far:

```
def TribRec(n) :
    if (n == 0 or n == 1 or n == 2) :
        return []
    elif (n == 3) :
        return [0,1][:n]
    else :
        sequence = TribRec(n-1)
        sequence.append(sequence[len(sequence)-1] + 
        sequence[len(sequence)-2] + sequence[len(sequence)-3])
        return sequence


def Trib(n) :
    for i in range(1, n) :
        print( TribRec(i) , " ", end = "")

# Driver code
n = 10
Trib(n)
```

When I run this code, I get the following output:

```
[]  []  [0, 1]  [0, 1, 2]  [0, 1, 2, 3]  [0, 1, 2, 3, 6]  [0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 11]  [0, 1,2, 3, 6, 11, 20]  [0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 11, 20, 37]
```

Instead, I want the output of length = n which is 10 here in the form of:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 11, 20, 37, 68, 125]
```

How do I fix my current code?

Answer (score 2):

Your code can be written more succinctly as follows.

```
def TribRec(n) :
    if n in {0, 1, 2}:
        return n
    else :
        return TribRec(n-1) + TribRec(n-2) + TribRec(n-3)

def Trib(n) :
    for i in range(0, n) :
        yield TribRec(i)

res = list(Trib(10))

# [0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 11, 20, 37, 68, 125]
```

**Explanation**

- As per [@czr's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49591107/9209546), you can sum the last 3 calls to `TribRec` recursively.
- Return `n` if it belongs to the set `{0, 1, 2}`.
- For `Trib(n)`, use a generator to remove boilerplate code (list instantiation, appending to list).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning a list in every recursive call, return the nth element and aggregate the list on the `Trib` function:

```
def TribRec(n) :
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    elif n == 2:
        return 2
    else :
        return TribRec(n-1) + TribRec(n-2) + TribRec(n-3)


def Trib(n) :
    l = []
    for i in range(0, n) :
        l.append(TribRec(i)) 
    return l
# Driver code
n = 10
Trib(n)
```

Comment: This is a much simpler version. Thank you so much for this. I understand this much better now.

Answer (score 0):

This is much more simple:

```
def trib(n):
    if n < 3:
        return n
    return trib(n-1) + trib(n-2) + trib(n-3)

def tri(n):
    result = []
    for i in range(0,n):
        result.append(trib(n))
    return result
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation of your code, particularly why it is "much more simple" than the other answer.

Comment: this doesn't have a lot of if inside, just if the number is < 3 you return your number, note that is only because you are doing a range(0,n); otherwise you have to be sure that the number is > 0